# How to get the value from array php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Here is my value for `print_r($_GET);`

the Output is

```
    Array(
    [prevurl() ] => Array(
        [taxirate] => 3500[Source] => Land[T] => Yes[TId] => 10[dtaxirate] => 4500[TD] => Yes[TDId] => 14[modeset] => minivan[minivanrate] => 400[Minivan] => Yes[MinivanId] => 6[FirstSearch] => FirstSearch[returnTrip] => yes[return -one] => No[Trip] => OneWay[TravelFrom] => Destination[TravelTo] => Pak[TravelDay] => 2015 - 08 - 16[TotalCount] => 1[Mode] => [Both] => [BothReturn] => 2015 - 08 - 17[Adults] => 1[Childs] => [Kids] => [Babies] =>
    )
)
```

I tried

`echo $_GET['prevurl']['taxirate'];` but it is not working.

How can i get the value of `taxirate`

```
<input type="hidden" value="Array
(
    [taxirate] => 3500
    [Source] => Land
    [T] => Yes
    [TId] => 10
    [dtaxirate] => 4500
    [TD] => Yes
    [TDId] => 14
    [modeset] => minivan
    [minivanrate] => 400
    [Minivan] => Yes
    [MinivanId] => 6
    [FirstSearch] => FirstSearch
    [returnTrip] => yes
    [return-one] => No
    [Trip] => OneWay
    [TravelFrom] => Hat Yai Airport
    [TravelTo] => Pak Bara
    [TravelDay] => 2015-08-16
    [TotalCount] => 1
    [Mode] => 
    [Both] => 
    [BothReturn] => 2015-08-17
    [Adults] => 1
    [Childs] => 
    [Kids] => 
    [Babies] => 
)
" name="prevurl">
```

**Update :**

**Note :**

Here is my `input` in the previous page

```
<input type="hidden" value="Array
(
    [taxirate] => 3500
    [Source] => Land
    [T] => Yes
    [TId] => 10
    [dtaxirate] => 4500
    [TD] => Yes
    [TDId] => 14
    [modeset] => minivan
    [minivanrate] => 400
    [Minivan] => Yes
    [MinivanId] => 6
    [FirstSearch] => FirstSearch
    [returnTrip] => yes
    [return-one] => No
    [Trip] => OneWay
    [TravelFrom] => Hat Yai Airport
    [TravelTo] => Pak Bara
    [TravelDay] => 2015-08-16
    [TotalCount] => 1
    [Mode] => 
    [Both] => 
    [BothReturn] => 2015-08-17
    [Adults] => 1
    [Childs] => 
    [Kids] => 
    [Babies] => 
)
" name="prevurl()">
```

**Actually the input was an array**

Comment: You have something weird going on with that first key, but probably: `$_GET['prevurl() ']['taxirate']`

Comment: Thanks, but it shows empty when i print it

Comment: why are you using `name="prevurl()"` ? just change `name="prevurl"`

Comment: Putting  a whole array in that field is straight up strange. You can't print an array in there like that. I mean you can technically...but it's strange...

Comment: Should be `name="prevurl"`

Comment: thanks, i changed to `prevurl` and your answer works @Rascaltt

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the array value is stored in a variable, I would try:

```
<?php
foreach ($array_data as $key=>$value)
{
    if($key == "prevurl")
    {
        foreach ($value as $key1=>$value1)
        {
            switch($key1)
            {
                case "taxirate":
                    $taxirate = $value1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

But I agree with Rasclatt. That array is odd looking/something weird with it.

Edit: Your original question looked like a multidimensional array, but your edit doesn't look multidimensional. My answer was from your original code.

Answer (score 0):

just change your hidden input fields name to `name="prevurl"`. And get your value of taxirate as:

```
$_GET['prevurl']['taxirate'];
```